# xcode 4.5, view size not editable in interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I started my project since xcode 4.4, and I have created several view controllers with interface builder (with xib files). Several days ago, I upgraded the xcode to version 4.5. Today, I suddenly found that I could modify view size anymore in interface builder. Is this an intended feature of xcode 4.5 or is it a bug of xcode 4.5?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A view has a Size popup menu in its Simulated Metrics panel (in the Attributes inspector); set that to Freeform and the view becomes manually resizable.

Comment: Amazing, thanks!  Setting to Freeform make auto-layout to work on my subviews.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same impression the first time i attempted to resize a view. You just have to go to the **INSPECTOR : Simulated Metrics :** and change the "Size" to "**FreeForm**" and there you'll be able to resize your view as much as you want! hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

And in XCode 5.x, it is completely removed...

...not really, but...

...look below the window, and you will find 4 anonymous icons where you can go bananas with adjusting view behaviour etc.

It sure took me a while to find, but now that I know where to look...