# Can I get more height for UIView with xcode5?

Tags: ios7, interface-builder, xcode5

I design one menu with InterfaceBuilder by xcode5, I am using UIView as menu container, but there are too many menu items, can I make the UIView height to be more large? so I can put these menu items down.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode 4.5, view size not editable in interface builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653786/xcode-4-5-view-size-not-editable-in-interface-builder)

Comment: See 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12653825/341994

And you might want to use a UIScrollView. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151624/add-ui-elements-to-uiscrollview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try set the **Simulated Metrics** size to freeform and set view height in the **Size Inspector**
[image]

but i suggest you to use UITableView and customize cell, it's more suitable for a scroll menu container.

Comment: Thanks, could you please tell me where to set  Simulated Metrics ?

Comment: Attributes Inspector.

Comment: how about to use UIScrollView ?